# Finding ConnectivityNumber algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I want find Connectivity number in Java. when i try to execute code,any message is not shown(empty)in console. no error message in window o.s. program execute well but when i try again in Linux, error message is shown that  no suitabe method 'main' in class.

ConnectivityNumber.java

```
public class ConnectivityNumber
{
    final private int graph[][]={
            {0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
    };
    private int vertex[]={1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    private int connectivityNum=0;
    private int startVertex=0;

    public boolean isFinishCount()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<vertex.length;i++)
        {
            if(vertex[i]==0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void randomChoose()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<vertex.length;i++)
        {
            if(vertex[i]==0)
                startVertex=i;
        }
    }

    public void chooseVertex(int index)
    {
        startVertex=index;
        if(vertex[index]==1)
        {
            connectivityNum++;
            randomChoose();
        }
        else
        {
            vertex[index]=1;
        }
    }

    public void rowSearch(int row)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<vertex.length;i++)
        {
            if(graph[row][i]==1&&vertex[i]==0)
            {
                chooseVertex(i);
                break; 
            }
        }
    }

    public void findConnectivityNum()
    {
        while(!isFinishCount())
        {
            rowSearch(startVertex);
        }
    }

    public void printConnectivityNum()
    {
        System.out.println(connectivityNum);
    }
}
```

ConnectivityNumberTest.java

```
public class ConnectivityNumberTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ConnectivityNumber connect=new ConnectivityNumber();
        connect.findConnectivityNum();
        connect.printConnectivityNum();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do?

Comment: Is this a dynamic connectivity problem? Please post some expected I/O